# Copying Structure's Object to a File stream, Writing it in a different Object

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm copying an object's data to a File Stream and then, from the same file stream, I'm writing that data to another object, but it fails. If I create another file stream and then i do the same process, it works.

The Non-Working Code

```
struct customer
{
    char name[23];
    float balance;
};

main()
{
    customer savac,s;
    strcpy(savac.name,"Tina Marshall");
    savac.balance=213123; 
    fstream fout("text.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    fout.write((char*)&savac,sizeof(customer));
    fout.read((char*)&s,sizeof(customer));
    cout<<s.name;
    cout<<"\n"<<s.balance;
}
```

The Working Code

```
struct customer
{
    char name[23];
    float balance;
};

main()
{
    customer savac,s;
    strcpy(savac.name,"Tina Marshall");
    savac.balance=213123;
    fstream fout("text.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    fout.write((char*)&savac,sizeof(customer));
    fstream fin("text.txt");
    fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(customer));
    cout<<s.name;
    cout<<"\n"<<s.balance;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to seek to 0?

Comment: That worked ! Added `seekg(ios::beg)`

Comment: Sidenote: As far as I know casting a struct or class to char* can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: What's better to use ?

Comment: You can either read and write the properties individually or create serialization functions

Comment: I'll note that down ! Thanks. I'm totally new to File Handling, I guess I need to read more

Comment: @ThomasSparber Only if the members aren't trivially copyable, which these are.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you're right, but it was just a recommendation. Because if he adds for example a virtual destructor then it can result in undefined behavior.